# What are the chance of getting a business schengen visa within 10 days of applying?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, france

I have my Schengen visa appointment on 2nd May. My travel date is 12th May. My visa type is business. My residing country is India (Kolkata). Is there any chance I get the visa?

Comment: Answer depends partly on the consulate where you apply and partly on your application quality (No missing documents etc.). As it stands, IMO this is opinion based (mostly because it asks for predicting chance).

Comment: We can't take bets, but 10 days sounds reasonable enough. Close voting as 'opinion-based'.